# internet connection and checking it

Tags: android

please see the following code. when I install the following code in my device and then I open the program immediately after installation, I see the following result:

```
Please Try
```

But when I close the program and I want reopen the program stops. Why? Where is the problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
TextView textView;
NetworkInfo networkInfo;
boolean v;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
       v = networkInfo.isConnected();
        if( v == false)
        textView.setText("Please Try");
        else if(v == true)
    textView.setText("Connect");
    }
```

Comment: how is it crashing ? Did you add `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` to the manifest?

Comment: Can you also show the rest of the overridden methods?

Comment: Thank you. But no need. I tested the code in a device with android version 4.2 and it can run the code well. But the code can not run in device with android version 2.3 well. While I use **minSdkVersion** equal to **8**. Please see **my minefest file**.

Comment: I updated my post. please see. thank you.

Comment: Very very excuse me. I have two program in my device and one of them has bad coding. I opened it due to distraction.My code is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

add this line in your AndroidManifest.xml file
after or before  this tag

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

or

```
<application>......</application>
```

Comment: Thank you. My code was correct. Due to distraction I opened another application.